# Why doesn't this work? (SproutCore & Todos Example)

Tags: sproutcore

I'm trying to modify the Todos Examples to get a better understanding of the framework.

I'm trying to modify the todosController to add a 'completed' computed property that returns all the completed todos. On top of this, I'm trying to get the 'areAllCompleted' property to update.

I have this code, which does not update 'areAllCompleted' when 'completed' has changed.

```
TodosThree.todosController = SC.ArrayController.create({
    completed: function(){
        if(this.get('content')){
            return this.get('content').find(
                SC.Query.local(
                    TodosThree.Todo,
                    'isCompleted = true'
                )
            );
        }
        else {
            return [];
        }
    }.property('content').cacheable(),
    areAllCompleted: function (k, v) {
        console.log('get');
        if (v !== undefined) {
            this.setEach('isCompleted', v);
        }

        return this.getPath('completed.length') === this.get('length');
            # This .property definition doesn't work with .*completed.length .. ?
    }.property('length','.*completed.length')
});
```

However, if I change the code slightly to add a binding, it works:

```
TodosThree.todosController = SC.ArrayController.create({
    completed: function(){
        if(this.get('content')){
            return this.get('content').find(
                SC.Query.local(
                    TodosThree.Todo,
                    'isCompleted = true'
                )
            );
        }
        else {
            return [];
        }
    }.property('content').cacheable(),
                                    # For some reason, this binding works ...
    completedLengthBinding: SC.Binding.oneWay('.*completed.length'),
    areAllCompleted: function (k, v) {
        console.log('get');
        if (v !== undefined) {
            this.setEach('isCompleted', v);
        }

        return this.getPath('completed.length') === this.get('length');
            # If I reference the binding that references completed, this now works ...
    }.property('length','completedLength')
});
```

Why does this subtle difference suddenly make it work?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `.property()` method, the parameters are expected to be direct properties of the object; so, it doesn't expand upon the property path that you are passing (`.*completed.length`). When you setup the binding, you are basically telling SproutCore that you want the path (`.*completed.length`) bound to a property of the object, which is why the second one works; since it has become a simple property.

Since you are setting both of these based off of the completion, another way that you could do it is by using a single function with `.observes()` which **does** follow property paths, but that is a bit complex. Following is how I would probably handle this:

```
/*
 * Note that using a store.find will auto-update when new todos are pushed
 * into the store, so there is no need to reset this every time.
 */
completed: TodosThree.store.find(
  SC.Query.local('TodosThree.Todo', 'isCompleted = true')
),


/*
 * Go ahead and grab the length so we can use it as a dependent property below
 */
completedLengthBinding: '*completed.length',


/*
 * Create the property function
 */
allAreCompleted: function(key, value) {
  if (value !== undefined) {
    this.setEach('isCompleted', value);
  }

  return this.everyProperty('isCompleted');
}.property('completed', 'completedLength')
```

A couple of things to note: since you're wanting to call `allAreCompleted()` and pass a value, you **DO** want this as a property, not just an observer. You could technically do it with a function that acts as both an observer and a property updater, but I think this is more clear.

Also, note the use of the [`everyProperty()`](http://docs.sproutcore.com/symbols/SC.PickerPane.html#doc=SC.Enumerable&method=everyProperty&src=false) method, which will iterate over each todo and ensure that the passed property is true for all todos.

Hope this helps! Please ask if you need clarification on anything :-D